# Google App Engine's RequestHandler.initilize() in Django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am wondering if Django has something similar like `RequestHandler.initialize()` from the [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass?csw=1#RequestHandler_initialize) that gets called before every request and I can initialize it on my views.py?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with django, but the framework you use is independant from the App Engine platform. Most of the sample code uses the webapp or webapp2 framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [Django middle ware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) and override the `process_request` function